# Iterate over a TreeMap of Objects (not Strings!!) in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration, treemap

I've got a Treemap of Servers:

```
TreeMap server_map = new TreeMap<String, Server>() ;
```

I'd like to iterate over the whole map to print all the servers. Using this kind of loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Server> entry : server_map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue().foo);
}
```

This won't work, because there is an *Unresolved compilation problem:*

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry

Isn't there a possibility to iterate over a Treemap of servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declaration to this:

```
TreeMap<String, Server> server_map = new TreeMap<String, Server>() ;
```

Comment: Oh of course! Sometimes you miss the forest for the trees. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that since java7 you do not need to declare the generic type on the right-hand-side, you can use the diamond-operator, saves some writing.

```
TreeMap<String, Server> server_map = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do it this way:

```
TreeMap server_map = new TreeMap();
for (Map.Entry entry : server_map.entrySet()){
 System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + ((Server)entry.getValue()).foo);
}
```

I just solved a problem similar to this one by doing something like this. If you use the `<String, Server>` way it will want you to use java 1.5 syntax.